While installing Kubuntu, boot/EFI is been allocated windows EFI partition rather than the partition I created on different disk
I installed Kubuntu on my other harddrive. It was working fine but as soon as I check me file system using 'df', it showed all the files are in their respective partion in other harddrive but boot/EFI is in main drive with windows. Even though I created seperate EFI partition, it automatically selects windows EFI while installing.
Screenshot of installation.
Kubuntu Installation https://imgur.com/a/QEhoCFl.
Also, what should be the path for Device for boot loader installation? Should it be the EFI partition I created or the harddrive where the EFI partition is created? Also the EFI partition in is ext4 format instead of fat32.

What version of Kubuntu? The ESP must be FAT32 with boot,esp flags. Older versions of Kubuntu and Ubuntu used Ubiquity installer with this bug, or they only installed grub bootloader to first drive, no matter what you specified. Work arounds in bug.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Kubuntu 24.04 uses Calamares installer that works to select any drive's ESP. I used it on external SSD and it worked.

@oldfred Kubuntu 22.04

When I used 22.04 and did not want grub in first drive, I had to use one of the work arounds in the bug report. My work around, unmounting incorrect ESP & mounting correct one, in middle of install. Easier fix for most, in bug report. Remove esp flag from Windows before install to second or external drive  Tim Richardson
https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator If you have ESP on 2nd or external drive, you can reinstall grub, either manually or using Boot-Repair's advanced mode & full reinstall of grub to correct drive.

@oldfred Thanks a lot. My problem was exactly that which was mentioned in this answer by Tim Richardson https://askubuntu.com/a/1056079/1813007 , and I solved using the steps mentioned. Thanks again
